# how to use Server.HtmlEncode with textbox in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

When i am entering a value like "" in textbox then its throwing following error.
[image]

Someone told me to use Server.HTMLencode/Server.HTMLdcode. but i dont know how to use it with textbox. Please help me.

Comment: Why do you want to support html in your textbox? Do you want to use it as a RichText Editor?

Comment: no actually our Project Manager has showed me a checklist in which this type of text also included so i am just working on that.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must pass special caracter in your textbox for example < or > ...

you can adjust ValidateRequest to false in order to authorize, you adjust on your page

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

link : http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow these values, add `ValidateRequest="false"` to the `<%@ page` declaration

Be aware that this does leave you more vulnerable to potential XSS attacks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET 4.5 you can set the requestValidationMode to 4.5:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
```

And then access the unvalidated querystring of form field data with:

```
Request.Unvalidated.Form["name"];
```

Then you can html decode the string to prevent XSS, I recommend to use the AntiXSS library for this (it's baked in ASP.NET 4.5).